# APPlitools: 401 unauthorized is displayed during the execution of checkWindow() function

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, applitools

I used the code below from your website and also provided my `APIKEY` from my account. The url is launched and the browser size is also set. When the first `checkWindow()` function executes, I get a 401 Unauthorized exception.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using Applitools;

namespace MyTests
{
    public class TestApplitoolsWebsite
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            // This is your api key, make sure you use it in all your tests.
            var eyes = new Eyes();
            eyes.ApiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";

            try
            {
                // Start visual testing with browser viewport set to 1024x768.
                // Make sure to use the returned driver from this point on.
                driver = eyes.Open(driver, "Applitools", "Test Web Page", new Size(1024, 768));

                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.applitools.com");

                // Visual validation point #1
                eyes.CheckWindow("Main Page");

                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".features>a")).Click();

                // Visual validation point #2
                eyes.CheckWindow("Features Page");

                // End visual testing. Validate visual correctness.
                eyes.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                eyes.AbortIfNotClosed();
                driver.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main purpose of Applitools API is that it will take screen shot and it will compare with baseline screen shot from my local. But during this `checkWindow()` function i get the exception.

Comment: Can't tell anything without knowing the `class Eyes`. Can you share what Eyes is doing?

Answer (score 3):

the reasons for 401 Unauthorized could be:
1) Wrong API key.
2) Not setting a server (for private clouds/on prem).

Do you have a dedicated cloud? If not, check to make sure that your API key is correct.

If it is and it is still not working, contact the Applitools team at support@applitools.com and they will be glad to assist.

Comment: Same also for JavaScript